# Getting hold of the document sets in a library

Tags: object-model, document-set

I am sure something wrong with the following code. There are over 400 document-sets in the library and script only shows 8. Please suggest which line is messed up. (At one time I could get this work)

```
$webUrl = "http://theportal.company.sales/sites/sales"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$list = $web.Lists["SalesScripts"]

foreach ($item in $list.Items  | Where-Object {$_.Folder -ne $null}) 
{
    try
    {   $field = $item["Title"]
Write-Host “Provisioning ” $item.Name
$ds = [Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSet]::GetDocumentSet($item.Folder)
$ds.Provision()
    }
    catch
    {
       write-host "something went wrong"
    }
}
$web.dispose()
```

Comment: Hey what happened. I thought I would get some hint from you all (the SP gurus)...

Comment: I totally understand your frustration. Don't expect high quality answer or quick turn around from this site. I face the same dilemma every time I post a question. I usually Google but I know sometimes that does not help. I would help but new to Doc Set. May want to revisit the content types associated with Doc Set. or may want to iterate another way so you get all the doc set that content type="Document Set" (or what ever the name of the doc set content type in your environment)

Answer (score 1):

Document Set is not a Folder. It inherits from Folder. So I suggest that you enumerate all items in the library and examine their "Content Type" Value then filter on that.

Answer (score 1):

The DocumentSet contentType is `0x0120D520`

So, to retrieve All your Document Set you can do something like that:

```
$SelectedItems = $list.Items |? {$_.ContentTypeId.ToString().StartsWith("0x0120D520")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply that code a bit

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://somesite"
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://somesite" #gets the root web of somesite
$subweb = Get-SPWeb "http://somesite/someweb" 

foreach($docsetFolder in $rootFolder.SubFolders | where { $_.Name -ne "Forms"})
{
        foreach ($doc in $docsetFolder.Files)
        {
                    $doc | Select Name, ContentTypeId | Sort Name
        }
}
```

Here is another method in C# so you have convert it to PS

```
public static bool IsDocumentSet(this SPListItem item)
{
 bool documentSetItem = false;
 DocumentSet documentSet = null;

 if (null != item && item.IsFolder())
 {
  documentSet = DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(item.Folder);

  if (null != documentSet)
   documentSetItem = true;
 }
 return documentSetItem;
}
```